# How to "dereference a type" in C++03?

Tags: c++, templates, traits, template-meta-programming, c++03

How do I get the "dereferenced type" of another type in C++03?  Note that it can be other dereferenceable type like `std::vector<int>::iterator`.

e.g. if I have

```
template<typename T>
struct MyPointer
{
    T p;
    ??? operator *() { return *p; }
};
```

How can I figure out what to replace the `???` with?

(**No Boost**! I want to know how to figure it out myself.)

Comment: Why not make the T the type that is being pointed at. That why you will know both the pointer type `T* p` and the type to return `T operator*()`

Comment: @Tux-D: Because you can't assume `p` is a pointer.

Comment: I must be missing something. I am saying you can explicitly make it a pointer by making T the type that is pointed at. Thus you define p as 'T* p'.

Comment: @Tux-D Mehrdad is saying that he doesn't want to restrict the templatized type to pointers only, since non-pointer types may overload `operator*` as well.

Comment: For anyone looking for the C++11 version of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471224/c11-how-to-get-the-type-a-pointer-or-iterator-points-to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, you can't. For raw pointers, you can partially specialize as shown in other answers- custom smart pointers may have a common typedef for the result type. However, you cannot write a single function that will cope with any pointer in C++03.

Comment: Seems like the correct answer, as much as I wasn't hoping for it to be. :) Thanks!

Comment: @DeadMG:  can't the return type simply be `typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type`?  Anything passed to a `MyPointer` class should probably also overload `iterator_traits`.

Answer (score 11):

```
template<typename>
struct dereference;

template<typename T>
struct dereference<T*>
{
    typedef typename T type;
};

template<typename T>
struct MyPointer
{
    T p;
    typename dereference<T>::type operator *() { return *p; }
};
```

Comment: Why complicate things with yet another template?

Comment: @Paul: Mehrdad asked how do dereference a type, I provided an answer.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Sure I can, the compiler will complain if you supply a non-pointer type.

Comment: This looks best. However, what about types that overload `operator*`?

Comment: FredOverflow: I was referring to what @UncleBens mentioned -- you can't be sure that `p` is a pointer. It might have just overloaded `operator*`.

Comment: That works in the simplest case, but needs handling for e.g. `int* const` or `int* volatile`. Also, what UncleBens said.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Do you want your program to work with non-pointer types that have an overloaded `operator*`, or do you want it to fail for those types?

Comment: Is there not a standard naming convention that recommends a type have the typedef(s) value_type/pointer_type/reference_type if it overloads operators like *? If you make that assumption then you can a default version of deference. It if they don't follow that convention you still get a compiler error (best of both worlds). Anyway +1,

Comment: @Mehrdad if it has overloaded `operator*`, then it's a class and you can require it to have a proper typedef or require it to specialize `dereference`

Answer (score 1):

You can have a simple construct which recursively removes all the pointers from a given type as below:

```
template<typename T>
struct ActualType { typedef T type; };
template<typename T>
struct ActualType<T*> { typedef typename ActualType<T>::type type; };
```

Below is the inline wrapper function to recursively find out the actual value from a given pointer or non-pointer types;

```
template<typename T>
typename ActualType<T>::type ActualValue (const T &obj) { return obj; }
template<typename T>
typename ActualType<T>::type ActualValue (T *p) { return ActualValue(*p); }
```

And just use it as:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyPointer
{
  T p;
  typename ActualType<T>::type operator *() { return ActualValue(p); }
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

In this example, it removes all the pointers from a given type, but as per the need you can configure the `ActualType<>` and `ActualValue<>`. There won't be any compiler error even if you declare `MyPointer<>` with a non-pointer type.

Here is a working [demo](http://ideone.com/AoVsLX) for a single pointer and no pointer types.

Comment: But that has the problem described in the comments to Paul Manta's old answer. It doesn't work for types that are not pointer types. `operator*` can be overloaded for a non-pointer type.

Comment: @jogojapan, it will work. See the edited answer with [demo](http://ideone.com/AoVsLX).

Comment: That seems to be a special case, where `MyPointer<T>` has its `operator*` defined such it returns an object of type `ActualType<T>::type`. But how do you get this to work if you have an arbitrary class, with an  `operator*` that returns an arbitrary data type?

Comment: @jogojapan, then it will be a compiler error and I don't think OP has any intention to return any arbitrary type. One has to use `ActualType<>` and `ActualValue<>` in combination to get the real object type and value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, and it is ensured that the template will only compile when you pass pointers to it:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyPointer<T*>
{
    T* p;
    T operator*() { return *p; }
}
```

Comment: @Mehrad Yes you can. In fact you are sure of it. Look at the second line of the code, and see the specialization of the template.

Comment: I mean you cannot assume that `p` is a pointer **in my example**. It may simply be that `p` has `operator*` overloaded instead.