# C++11: How to get the type a pointer or iterator points to?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

To be more specific, suppose I am writing `template<class Pointer> class Foo` and I want to declare a `typedef` inside the class for the type that `*p` would have if `p` were of type `Pointer`.

In C++03, as far as I am aware, the only way to do this is with something like

```
typename std::iterator_traits<Pointer>::reference
```

The disadvantage of this method is that it won't work if `Pointer` is some custom iterator type and the author forgot to extend `std::iterator` or otherwise define a `std::iterator_traits` specialization.

In C++11, my colleague suggested

```
decltype(*Pointer())
```

But this won't work if `Pointer` is not default-constructible, so he amended this to

```
decltype(**(Pointer*)0)
```

I tried this, and it worked, but then I thought that it looked a bit iffy because it involves the dereference of a null pointer, and thus might not be standards-compliant.

Can we do better?

Comment: For what it's worth, here is the C++03 version of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302053/how-to-dereference-a-type-in-c03 (But not a duplicate, of course)

Comment: There will be those who disagree, but I claim that not providing appropriate iterator_traits for an iterator is a *bug*. A reasonable workaround, when you find such a bug -- and you'll find it because it will lead to a compiler error -- is to specialize std::iterator_traits for the offending "iterator" until you hunt down its authors and show them the error of their ways. ("iterator" in quotes, because it's not an iterator if it doesn't have iterator_traits.)

Comment: Can you clarify if you want the `reference` type or the `value_type`?  I.e. if `Pointer` is `int*`, do you want `int` or `int&`?

Comment: @HowardHinnant, I originally wanted the `value_type`, but decided the question would be more simply expressed in the present form. Besides, I know about `std::remove_reference`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're right to be cautious about dereferencing a null pointer, but the fact is that it's ok here! `decltype` does not evaluate its operand, so dereferencing a null pointer inside is perfectly valid.

The proper solution, however, is `std::declval`, introduced inside `<utility>` in C++11:

```
decltype(*std::declval<Pointer>())
```

Comment: I read on Wikipedia that `#define offsetof(st, m) ((size_t)(&((st *)0)->m))` is not standards-compliant in C because it dereferences a null pointer. Is it true that this construction _does_ evaluate, which makes it different?

Comment: @BrianBi, A `#define` is just text replacement. If you use the macro in a context where it is evaluated, then yes, it's undefined behaviour. If you're interested, I also found a somewhat related [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766559/c-sometype-0/13767066#13767066) discussing the construct in your question.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, an expression like `int x = offsetof(st, m);` would give undefined behaviour, whereas one like `int y = sizeof(offsetof(st, m))` wouldn't (and would just evaluate to 4 or 8 or whatever the size of a `size_t` is)?

Comment: Am I missing something, or doesn't that need have a `*`? `decltype(*std::declval<Pointer>())`

Comment: @BrianBi, As far as I can tell, it would depend on the usage context, yes.

Comment: @BrianBi `sizeof`(in C++) is a compile time construct, therefore there is no such thing as dereferencing a null-pointer in a `sizeof` expression. It just evaluates the types of the expression involved, and retrieves its size.

Comment: @BrianBi: when the compiler sees a 0 pointer it may substitute some other sentinel value that's platform appropriate.  For example, it might be that memory on some platform doesn't start at 0, and the CPU creates an interrupt/trap if an address register is loaded with a value that doesn't correspond to actual memory, so the compiler might use another value instead but needs to ensure == 0, use in a boolean context etc. works as expected.  So, what's `&(st*)0` going to be on such a platform?  Not just an offset in bytes into the object....  decltype differs because it's not using the value.

Comment: @BrianBi: You hit the nail on the head. Even your word choice matches the standard. `sizeof` is not an "evaluated context", not even a "potentially evaluated context". Your `offsetof` macro is intended to be used in evaluated contexts. A null-pointer dereference is problematic in (potentially) evaluated contexts.

Comment: I am getting this error while using this: `'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type`. Is there a way to resolve this error?

Comment: @In78, Indeed, you can't dereference `void*`. The other answer will still work in this case, and in C++11 the standard library offers it under the name [`std::remove_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer). That's probably what I'd recommend using in general, it's just not what the poster was trying to do. However, it works only for raw pointers whereas dereferencing supports other pointer-like types such as `optional` and smart pointers.

Comment: @chris: I am still getting some trouble. I have posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66478991/how-to-use-stdremove-pointer-with-void

Answer (score 3):

In C++03 you can write a simple construct which will remove all the pointers from the given type:

```
template<typename T>
struct ActualType { typedef T type; };
template<typename T>
struct ActualType<T*> { typedef typename ActualType<T>::type type; };
```

If you pass `int*` or `int**` then finally the `ActualType<T>::type` will boil down to `int`.

Here is a [demo](http://ideone.com/vIQTeV);

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, you can use [`std::remove_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer)

```
using PType = std::remove_pointer<Pointer>::type;
```

Comment: This does not exist??

Comment: @Vero whoops, I used the wrong name. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Do iterator traits with a `SFINAE` fallback to dereferencing.

Rather than dereference null, create a template function that returns `std::decay<T>&` then dereference that.