# How to use std::remove_pointer with void*?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, void-pointers, type-traits

I am using `std::unique_ptr` in this way:

```
template <typename Pointer, auto deleter>
using my_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<Pointer>, std::integral_constant<decltype(deleter), deleter>>;
```

It seems to work when `Pointer = void*`, but when trying to use reset on such a `my_unique_ptr`, I am getting this error:

```
invalid conversion from 'SampleType' {aka 'void*'} to 'std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<void*>, std::integral_constant<...> >::pointer' {aka 'std::remove_pointer<void*>*'}
```

Shouldn't `std::remove_pointer<void*>*` automatically mean `void*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `my_unique_ptr<void*>` does not contain `void*`. It contains a `std::remove_pointer<void*>*`.

> Shouldn't `std::remove_pointer<void*>*` automatically mean `void*`?

The `std::remove_pointer` type is not magic. It's a type like any other. Here's a possible implementation:

```
template<typename T>
struct remove_pointer {
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
struct remove_pointer<T*> {
    using type = T;
};
```

As you can see, as you defined it, the `std::unique_ptr` contains a pointer to that struct, just like the compiler error mentionned.

What you probably meant to do is to use the member `::type` of the struct, aka the result of the `remove_pointer` metafunction:

```
template <typename Pointer, auto deleter>
using my_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<typename std::remove_pointer<Pointer>::type, std::integral_constant<decltype(deleter), deleter>>;
```

And with C++14, there's a alias to simplify:

```
template <typename Pointer, auto deleter>
using my_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer_t<Pointer>, std::integral_constant<decltype(deleter), deleter>>;
```